# error when disabling remote blob storage

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, remote-blob-store

I'm trying to disable remote blob storage on a Sharepoint 2010 content database. I'm using this powershell command

```
$dbs = Get-SPSite -Limit All | Where-Object { $_.Url -like '<networkurl>' } | Get-SPContentDatabase

    if ($dbs -ne $null)
    {
        # loop through each content database
        foreach ($cdb in $dbs)
        {
            Write-Output $cdb

            $rbs=$cdb.RemoteBlobStorageSettings
            $rbs.GetProviderNames()
            $rbs.SetActiveProviderName("")
            $rbs.Migrate() 
            $rbs.Disable()
        }
    }
```

The Migrate() command processes about 10000 records and then it gets to one particular record (which I'm not sure what it is), it just hangs.

Looking at the event log, I can see this error

> Unknown SQL Exception 201 occurred. Additional error information from
>   SQL Server is included below.
>
> Procedure or function 'proc_SetDatabaseInformation' expects parameter
>   '@Value', which was not supplied.

I'm not sure what I can do. According to this [article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/76e81fca-45eb-4ad0-a1ee-47e8d6718e23/bug-in-sharepoint-2010-when-disabling-remote-blob-storage-rbs?forum=sharepointadminprevious), it looks like it could be a Sharepoint 2010 bug. However, it offers no solution.

I'm wondering what I can do? How do I identify which blob is the problem?  Is it possible to get Migrate to display more logging or for Migrate to skip over any documents it has problems with.